# Conditional replace only in first x characters

Tags: mysql

I have a rather large MySQL database which I'm currently working with. It stores general contact information. The table name is 'customers' and the column I'm looking to change is called 'serviceNumber'.

We've just discovered that we're going to need to go though and change the format of a lot of the records. Here are the details:

Most phone numbers in this column include our country code ('61400000000'), and some are formatted just as local numbers ('0400000000').
I'm aware that I can tell MySQL to go through and just replace all occurrences of '614' with '04', but the issue is that a lot of the numbers happen to contain '614' in the actual phone number itself.

How would I go about replacing this only for the records that **start with** '614'?

Answer (score 0):

I would be using the following approach:

```
update customers
   set serviceNumber = concat ('04', substring (serviceNumber, 4))
 where serviceNumber like '614%';
```

The `where` clause restricts the `update` to those rows that have a number ***beginning*** with `614`, while the `set` changes it to be `04`, followed by the current number with the `614` removed.

---

However, you *may* want to do some extra sanity checking such as ensuring the length is correct.

Those are Australian numbers I presume (given the `+61` prefix and the fact you're based out of Sydney) and you might be interested to know that my local (eight-digit) number starts with `616` (we're pretty strange over here on the west coast).

There may be others out there that begin `614` and you wouldn't want to be changing someone's ***local*** number `61431415` into `0431415`.

Since the mobile phones in Australia are all (currently) `614xx yyy zzz`, a good first cut would be:

```
update customers
   set serviceNumber = concat ('04', substring (serviceNumber, 4))
 where serviceNumber like '614%'
   and char_length(serviceNumber) >= 11;
```

You might also be interested in the fact that ACMA expect to start allocating `05` mobile numbers in 2017 when the current `04` ones start running out. If you're interested in forward thinking, you probably should at least *consider* that as well.

Comment: Pretty comprehensive. Cheers. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableName set number = concat ('04', substring (number, 4)) where number like '614%';
```

this may help you here
1 first replacing with first 3 digits
then we did concat the existing numbers with 04

Comment: You _are_ aware that this appears to be exactly what I'd already posted but with less explanation and incorrect column names? :-)

Comment: You must be a slow typer, given there's a full 15 minutes between the two answers :-) Don't worry, I'm not having a go at you, just thought it was unnecessary providing another answer that said pretty much exactly the same thing. The OP/swarm can decide which is the best.